# Complexity/big theta of loop with multiplicative increment of i

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm trying to find the time complexity/ big theta of the following:

```
def f(n):
    i = 2
    while i <n:
        print(i)
        i = i*i
```

The only approach of how I know how to solve this is to find a general formula for i_k and then solve the equation of i_k >= n, however I end up with a log(logn/log2)/log(2) equation as my k value, and that seems awefully wrong to me and I'm not sure how I would translate that into a big theta expression. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer looks good, actually! If you rewrite log x / log 2 as log<sub>2</sub> x (or lg x, for short), what you have is that the number of iterations is lg lg n. Since the value of i in iteration k of the loop is 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>, this means that the loop stops when i reaches the value 2<sup>2<sup>lg lg n</sup></sup> = 2<sup>lg n</sup> = n, which matches the loop bound.

More generally, the number of times you can square a value before it exceeds n is Θ(log log n), and similarly the number of square roots you can take before you drop a number n down to a constant is Θ(log log n), so your answer is pretty much what you’d expect.